# How to catch WebSocketSubject error if server is not available?

Tags: angular, websocket, error-handling, rxjs

I have a WebSocket service in Angular 8 that works fine (in general). I connect to the socket like this:

```
    public connect(): void {
        this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject({
                        url: CONTENT_SERVER_URL,
                       });

        this.socket$
            .subscribe(
                (message) => {
                    this.serverMessages.push(message);
                },
                (error) => {    
                    this.status = Status.ERROR;
                },
                () => {
                    this.status = Status.CLOSED;
                }
            );
    }
```

and send messages in this way:

```
    public send(message: Message): void {
        if (this.status != Status.CONNECTED)
            this.connect();

        this.socket$.next(message);
    }
```

The problem is now that the server is not always online and then I get this message in the console:

```
WebSocketSubject.js:91 WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYDNS.XXX:7031/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502
```

How can I catch this message, so that it isn't printed to the console? (`try() catch()` doesn't work)

Comment: it is not caught by subscribe error handler?

Comment: The subscribe() error handler works find. But I see also this console message...

Comment: I would also like to get ahold of this error message so I can get the response code. Not sure how thought.